# Markdown table not making column wide enough

Tags: python, markdown

I have this Markdown code in jupyter lab.

Code: [Image of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5scl5.png)

```
| Phenomanae               | Originial Equations                                   | Approximate  |
|--------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|              |
|Radiation                 |$Q_{R} = A\epsilon\sigma (T^{4}_{plate} - T^{4}_{air})$|wwwwwwwwwww   |
|Conduction with Work Roll |$Q_{Cond} = -kA\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}$          |wwwwwwwwwww   |
|Convection with Air       |$Q_{Air} = hA(T_{plate}-T_{air})$                      |wwwwwwwwwww   |
|Convection with Descaler  |$Q_{Desc} = h_w A_w(T_{plate} - T_{water})$            |wwwwwwwwwww   |
|Deformation               |$Q_{Desc} = h_w A_w(T_{plate} - T_{water})$            |wwwwwwwwwww   |
```

[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8ruW.png)

The middle column is only as long as the title "Original Equations". How do I get the column to automate its width to accommodate the equations too.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can put your table in custom class, and style it using css. This way you can set constant width for your 2nd column

```html
<div class="foo">
| Phenomanae               | Originial Equations                                   | Approximate  |
|--------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|              |
|Radiation                 |$Q_{R} = A\epsilon\sigma (T^{4}_{plate} - T^{4}_{air})$|wwwwwwwwwww   |
|Conduction with Work Roll |$Q_{Cond} = -kA\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}$          |wwwwwwwwwww   |
|Convection with Air       |$Q_{Air} = hA(T_{plate}-T_{air})$                      |wwwwwwwwwww   |
|Convection with Descaler  |$Q_{Desc} = h_w A_w(T_{plate} - T_{water})$            |wwwwwwwwwww   |
|Deformation               |$Q_{Desc} = h_w A_w(T_{plate} - T_{water})$            |wwwwwwwwwww   |
</div>

<style>
    .foo table {
        ...
    }
</style>
```